# how to create a new filtered sequence from another

Tags: filter, sequence, freemarker

If I have a sequence like:

```
<#assign seq = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']>
```

I'd need to obtain some new sequences that are *filtered* versions of the original one. For example:

```
<#assign seq1 = ['a', 'b']>
<#assign seq2 = ['b', 'd', 'e']>
```

I thought about the `filter` [built-in](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_filter) but how to add more than one condition? For example, something like:

```
seq?filter(x -> (x == 'a' OR x == 'b'))
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like `seq?filter(x -> x == 'a' || x == 'b')`. The part after the `->` is just any expression that evaluates to a boolean value, so of course it can use `||`, `&&`, call functions, etc.